# Does overriding the GetHashCode method mean used values should never change?

Tags: c#, gethashcode

If I have a class with properties

```
public class a{
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public int d;
}
```

And I override the GetHashCode method in the class with

```
public class a
{
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public int d;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
         int hashCode = base.GetHashCode();
         hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + a.GetHashCode();
         hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + b.GetHashCode();
         hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + c.GetHashCode();
         return hashCode;
    }

   public override bool Equals(){
   ...
   }
}
```

Does this mean that a, b, or c should never change? Otherwise the GetHashCode method becomes useless? Due to the fact that changing properties will generate different hashcodes, and the object at one time does not equal the object at another later state? Usually this should probably be correct, but I am having weird binding issues that seem to suggest I should not be doing this.

I think I was reading something on this, but I wanted to verify that this is true. It just seems like properties change in objects all the time, so it doesn't seem even safe to even override GetHashCode() for 99% of my use cases, where you don't want things to break if you change the object, if this is the case.

Thanks.

override without repurcussions

Comment: Why would it be useless?

Comment: I have updated the question with some more info.

Comment: @Blindy - It's useless if it changes.

Comment: Surely you mean *the collection* is useless if the hash code of its members changes. Are you commenting on the same question as me? Cause this question doesn't mention collections, only hash codes, and the `GetHashCode` function works just fine with mutable fields in general.

Comment: @Blindy - I wouldn't say "works just fine". By design there is a use for that figure and that use assumes it is immutable.

Comment: "Otherwise the GetHashCode method becomes useless" - yes, it becomes useless.

Comment: Again, you're talking about the collections that make use of it, and their (and your?) assumptions of it. There's nothing stopping you from writing a better collection that listens to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and refreshes the object internally on changes, if that's what you wish.

Comment: @Blindy - No, I'm talking about the expected behaviour of `GetHashCode`. There's a design contract that needs to be adhered to, regardless of if it's used in collections or not.

Comment: Side note: you can use `return HashCode.Combine(a, b, c, base.GetHashCode());`

Comment: @Enigmativity, you are so close to getting it every time you mention a "contract", because contracts are binary operations, they happen *between your class and something else*. Specifically, the built-in collections that have the expectation that you keep repeating. With collections designed with mutability in mind (as I mentioned above), a new contract will be used with `GetHashCode`, specifically one that doesn't have the previous limitation.

Comment: @Blindy - Contracts can be behavioural too. I don't understand the second part of your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically yes, if you are using the class in some data structure which stores it relying on the hash code value (like a key in the dictionary for example), then values used to calculate the hash code should remain the same.

Docs for `Object.GetHashCode` have a section on this topic, called [Notes to Inheritors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#notes-to-inheritors). In short you should try avoiding overriding `GetHashCode` for mutable reference types:

> You can override `GetHashCode()` for immutable reference types. In general, for mutable reference types, you should override `GetHashCode()` only if:
>
> - You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable;
> - You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code.
>
> Otherwise, you might think that the mutable object is lost in the hash table. If you do choose to override `GetHashCode()` for a mutable reference type, your documentation should make it clear that users of your type should not modify object values while the object is stored in a hash table.

Similar advice can be found also in the [Equality Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/equality-operators) doc.